# ssh use known_hosts other than $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Is it possible to run SSH using another `known_hosts` file than the standard `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` for the user?

Note, that SSH uses `$HOME` original for the user. If you try to change it, e.g.

```
export HOME=some_other_location
```

it does not affect the location SSH uses to look for `known_hosts`.

Comment: Yes. ~/.ssh/known_hosts2 . We symlink it to a file in our synced files folder. Any new server fingerprint is added there and everybody has instant access.

Answer (score 95):

You may specify an alternative known_hosts file in `$HOME/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, the parameter `UserKnownHostsFile`.

Alternatively, if you prefer to use alternative known_hosts file for a specific SSH invocation, you may use the SSH command option `-o UserKnownHostsFile=<alternative known_hosts file>`, e.g. `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=~/my_temporary_known_host ssh_host`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to avoid modifications in these configuration files, but it seems to be impossible. ;-(   S.R.

Comment: Modifying the user's own `$HOME/.ssh/config` should not be a big problem, but `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` maybe. Or, you can specify that parameter on the ssh command line, i.e. `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=somewhere someone@ssh_host`

Comment: The `ssh -o` option is the correct answer to this question.  It should also be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Answer modified as per suggested, providing both methods to the readers.

Comment: I've added this option into `$HOME/.ssh/config` in my `Host *` global section and it works for all host aliases.