# appleboy/ssh-action No such device or address error

Tags: laravel, ssh, devops, github-actions

I'm trying to create an auto-deploy file for laravel project.

Here is my code of the yml file.
jobs:
deploy:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2 
- name: Deployment
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
 
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
    script: |
      cd path-to-my-directory

      git pull
      php artisan migrate
```

git pull returns `could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address` error. But I sure that `username, key, host` are set properly.
Can't solve the problem or find a similar issue with solution

Answer (score 1):

If you set an SSH key, while your URL is an HTTPS one, said key would not be used. At all.

Instead, Git, in the GitHub Action, would try and get the credentials (username/password) for the private repository through HTTPS.

Plus, an SSH URL would use the username `git` anyway, alongside the private SSH key which allows the remote server to authenticate the actual user.

You can [see here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63012327/6309) of a GitHub Action actually using an SSH URL:

```yaml
on: [push]

jobs:
  try-ssh-commands:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: SSH MY_TEST
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: test_ssh
        uses: ./
        with:
          ssh_key: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
          known_hosts: ${{secrets.SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS}}
```

---

If you are using HTTPS however, and as noted in the comments be the OP:

- you need a PAT (Personal Access Token)
- you need to store it: `git config credential.helper store` + `git pull`.

Comment: As I noticed Github not using a username password pair actually. if I want to pull manually I have to use  Personal access tokens. But the issue I fixed by running `git config credential.helper store` and the `git pull` manually. after that the workflow runs as expected

Comment: @TakhtakTeam Great, well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I got something similar working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76961475/1964277)

Comment: @rupweb Nice. That should too indeed.